# send value from one jsp to another jsp using href

Tags: java, jsp

How to send `resultset.getInt(1)` this value to another jsp page ,I am trying this but not working.

```
<td><a href="result.jsp?Id="+<%=resultset.getInt(1)%> ><%= resultset.getInt(1) %></a></td>
```

result.jsp

```
<% 
String ss =request.getParameter("Id");
System.out.println("my value" + ss);
%>
```

I m getting `""` in `result.jsp`.

Comment: `resultset.getInt(1)` what is its value in first jsp?

Comment: y dont u just pass it as an attribute in request scope ??

Comment: did you check whether resultset.getInt(1) is returning values?

Comment: Are you aware that - `<%=resultset.getInt(1)%>` is similar to `out.println(resultset.getInt(1));`? So, you cannot expect `sysout` to return any value to be stored in `href` in your `a` tag. So, just remove that `<%=.. %>` from the ends. Keep it like - `<a href="result.jsp?Id="+ resultset.getInt(1)>` and see if it works

Comment: I think you should put a space like this <%= resultset.getInt(1) %>

Comment: @BhavikShah : yes resultset.getInt(1) is returning values..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td>
    <a href=<%= "\"result.jsp?Id=" + resultset.getInt(1) + "\"" %> ><%= resultset.getInt(1) %></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the generated HTML. It looks like the result of the first `<%=resultset.getInt(1)%>` is written outside the value of the href. This might work better:

```
<td><a href="result.jsp?Id=<%=resultset.getInt(1)%>" ><%= resultset.getInt(1) %></a></td>
```

On a side note I would sugest you take a look at expression language and use that instead of inlining java code in your JSP. It is hard to debug and maintain such code.

Comment: thanks for quick response.it's not outside of the value of href.

Answer (score 1):

this is our first page :-

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8" import="java.util.*;" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="xp.jsp" method="get">
<input type="text" value="" name="lol">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
<a href="xp.jsp?lol=hahah">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and this our xp.jsp:-

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%=request.getParameter("lol") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have used both the ways to pass the data from one jsp to another jsp

Comment: What if href="xp.jsp?lol=hahah haa"  space is there ? , value get truncated after space , please advise